# What exactly does Valgrind take in to account when giving the number of allocations?

Tags: c, linux, valgrind

I'm currently recoding the C/C++ `malloc` function for Linux usage only. One of the challenges of that exercise is to make my function as close to the original `malloc` as possible.

I usually use Valgrind to check if my mallocs are correctly allowed and freed, but I don't know if Valgrind can pick other form of memory allocation, and if so, which ones?

Second question: assuming Valgrind doesn't pick other forms of memory allocation, what else could I use to check if my function is working as intended?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding this question. The title mentions "allocs number" but that is not explained in the question itself, and it's a bit too vague for such a low-level topic. Perhaps it's just me.

Comment: When using valgrind, you recieve a heap summary that gives you an alloc number. This alloc number is the number of memory blocks used by your program, which is how you know how much memory you allocated. I want to know if Valgrind only gets that number by looking at malloc calls.

Comment: There is no C/C++ language. `malloc` is a C function and you should not use it in C++.

Comment: Valgrind must at least take into account `calloc()` and `realloc()` when counting the allocations.  Accounting for `realloc()` is really hard: `void *space = realloc(0, 128);` is equivalent to `malloc()`, while `void *space = realloc(data, 0);` is equivalent to `free()`.

Comment: There might help: http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.mempools and https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=219156  (from http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.debugging.valgrind/12070)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Valgrind assumes `malloc` to work as expected in order to manage memory allocation. If your goal is to make your own `malloc` implementation, you cannot use Valgrind to debug it.

This is one of the challenge of this exercise: you have to debug it yourself.

If you want to check if your function works as intended, code a function `show_alloc_mem` that dumps your memory and check if everything is displayed as you intended.

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer and quick answer, I will be sure to use that to debug it.